# How to place "jetty.jmxrmiport" system property from predefined property

Tags: xml, jetty

I am using Jetty configuration file, and I want to use "jetty.jmxrmiport" from properties I have defined earlier.

Currently, I am using:

```
<SystemProperty name="jetty.jmxrmiport" default="1099"/>
```

I want to use a variable instead of `1099`. Like in `propertyplaceholderconfigurer`, we can use `{$abc}`.

Is there any way to use a property here?

Answer (score 0):

The `"jetty.jmxrmiport"` is the name of the standard system property.

You can start jetty with `-Djetty.jmxrmiport=4099` if you want it to be a different value.